# Could I swap fork relationship between two git repos in Atlassian Stash

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

I have two git repos like below in [Atlassian Stash](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/server) / Bitbucket Enterprise. Repo2 is forked from repo1, but has no change yet.

I would like to change repo2 to be  master repo and repo1 to be fork of repo2. . How can I reverse the relation?

[image: two repos in stash server]

Answer (score 1):

You could just swap the origins.

```
$ cd repo1
$ git remote rm origin
$ git remote add origin git@url.ext:org/Repo2.git
```

then

```
$ cd repo2
$ git remote rm origin
$ git remote add origin git@url.ext:org/Repo1.git
```

Alternatively, add seperate origins.

```
$ cd repo1
$ git remote add actual git@url.ext:org/Repo2.git
$ git fetch actual

$ cd repo2
$ git remote add actual git@url.ext:org/Repo1.git
$ git fetch actual
```

Comment: That works for "local repository" I have access to. How can modify this in Stash server?